# Argument-dependent lookup within template

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm confused about function-name lookup in the context of a template.  I know that the compiler delays argument-dependent identifier lookup in templated code until the template is instantiated.  This means you can sometimes have syntax errors or call non-existent functions within templated code, and the compiler won't complain unless you actually instantiate the template.

However, I've found a discrepancy between different compilers, and I'm interested in knowing what the standard itself requires.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:

    template <class T>
    void bar(T v)
    {
        do_something(v);
    }
};

void do_something(std::string s)
{
    std::cout << "do_something(std::string)" << std::endl;
}

void do_something(int x)
{
    std::cout << "do_something(int)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar("abc");
    f.bar(123);
}
```

Note that the template member function `Foo::bar` calls a **non-argument-dependent global function** called `do_something`, which ***hasn't even been declared yet.***

Yet, GCC 4.6.3 will happily compile the above program.  When run, the output is:

```
do_something(std::string)
do_something(int)
```

[**Here's an ideone link**](http://ideone.com/l4Iz2c).

So, it looks as though the compiler delayed identifier lookup until after the template was instantiated, at which point it was able to find `do_something`.

In contrast, GCC 4.7.2 will **not** compile the above program.  It produces the following error:

```
test.cc: In instantiation of ‘void Foo::bar(T) [with T = const char*]’:
test.cc:27:13:   required from here
test.cc:10:3: error: ‘do_something’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
test.cc:19:6: note: ‘void do_something(int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
```

So, GCC 4.7.2 is aware that `do_something` is later declared, but refuses to compile the program because `do_something` is not argument-dependent.

So, I'm assuming GCC 4.7.2 is probably correct here, and GCC 4.6.3 is incorrect.  So presumably, I'd need to declare `do_something` before `Foo::bar` is defined.  The problem with this is suppose I want to allow users of my class `Foo` to extend the behavior of `Foo::bar` by implementing their own overloads of `do_something`.  I'd need to write something like:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void do_something(T v)
{
    std::cout << "do_something(T)" << std::endl;
}

class Foo
{
    public:

    template <class T>
    void bar(T v)
    {
        do_something(v);
    }
};

void do_something(int x)
{
    std::cout << "do_something(int)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar("abc");
    f.bar(123);
}
```

The problem here, is that the overloads of `do_something` are not visible from within `Foo::bar`, and thus never called.  So even if I call `do_something(int)`, it will call `do_something(T)` rather than the overload for `int`.  Thus, with both GCC 4.6.3 and GCC 4.7.2, the above program outputs:

```
do_something(T)
do_something(T)
```

So what are some solutions here?  How can I allow users to extend `Foo::bar` by implementing their own overloads of `do_something`?

Comment: Even introducing a "catch-all" with the least desirable conversion, the problem persists: http://ideone.com/OSGoqJ

Answer (score 3):

As far as overloading `do_something` goes, you need to specialize your original template:

```
template<>
void do_something<int>(int x) {
    std::cout << "do_something(int)" << std::endl;
}
```

---

**Edit :** As @MatthieuM. pointed out, function template specialization can yield weird results if you also need to overload the function (and at some point you'll probably need to, since function templates can't be partially specialized). See Matthieu's link to Herb Sutter's article [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) for a full explanation.

What is recommended instead is to use a static function wrapped in a struct, which allows partial specialization and removes that name resolution problem that comes with overloaded function templates.

```
template<typename T>
struct DoSomething {
    static void do_something(T v) {
        std::cout << "do_something(T)" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    template <class T>
    void bar(T v) {
        DoSomething<T>::do_something(v);
    }
};

// Now you can specialize safely
template<>
struct DoSomething<int> {
    static void do_something(int v) {
        std::cout << "do_something(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: It will work *here*, but that's a terrible idea in general. name lookup and template specialization interact in very strange ways.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Care to elaborate? As far as I understand template specialization (which may not be a *complete* understanding, I admit) the specialization is chosen at the instantiation point. I realize this is probably over-simplified but I never got bitten by this (even though I use it regularly) so I never dug deeper. ;)

Comment: It's best illustrated by Herb Sutters' [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). The point is that first the "real" function templates are looked-up, and the best match is chosen, and only then does the compiler look up if there is a specialization of that base function template to consider. So, to know whether you specialization is chosen or not, you need to know which base function template it's related to... it's weird, really, really, weird.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah thanks I understand now, this is confusing indeed (and I also understand why I never had any issues with this: I always use static functions wrapped in a struct to allow partial specialization -- funnily enough that's exactly what H.Sutter advises in his Moral#2 point). I'll edit my answer accordingly.